# How to avoid the borders/margins that arise from the body tag?

Tags: css, html

I'm new to CSS. I've got a deceptively simple problem. This is a fiddle of a simple page. 
http://liveweave.com/c6j68I

The objective is to show a fixed 900px white `div` centered against a coral background.

I've tried to achieve this using two `div`s maked `#outerWrapper` and `#wrapper`.

However, the whole page still seems to have a white background, which seems to be connected to the `body` tag. (Please use the fullscreen mode to see it).

If I give the `body` the background color of the `#outerWrapper`, again, the color appears on the top and bottom of the page too, which is undesired. (Please uncomment the CSS of body to see this.)

I've tried using the article tag; using negative margins; and changing dimesions of the body tag. Nothing seems to work.

In simple terms, a want a 'columned' look: coral-white-coral; instead of the 'boxed' look I currently have.

Please help.

Comment: Open the DevTools (press F12) and inspect the body element. By default, it has `body { margin: 8px; }` applied to it. You should overwrite that.

Comment: @akinuri: Thank you. It solves the 'side' problem; but I'm still getting a margin on the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing body margin in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208335/removing-body-margin-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a style for the `body` in your CSS and set the margin to 0px, like so:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Accepting because you answered the earliest. Btw, it fixed the problem partially. The top margin was still there. Found out it was coming from `h2` and set it to 0. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually thepio answered 7 seconds before I did. As much as I appreciate the reputation, I would be remiss if I didn't point this out.

Answer (score 2):

Because most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.

If you want to change it, you can just do this, add it on your css

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Want to be more complete?

use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). It resets a lot of default values to be consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Body has default margins set by the browser (most browsers set default styles to different elements and they can vary depending on the browser) as seen below in developer console.

**Note:** In most browsers you can open the developer console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> on your keyboard:

[image]

Just set the following css to avoid it:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://liveweave.com/EzWH0o

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following

```
<style>
   body,html {height:100vh; width:100vw; padding:0; margin:0;}
</style>
```