# How can I get rid of extra white space at the top?

Tags: html, css

it's me again, as im trying to learn I got to a frustrating part. First theres extra space [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TacL.png) at the top with every browser.
I alredy tried `body {overflow:auto;}` in the css but aparently only works till certain point and desapeared the extra space at the right but not at the top. I already tried resetting the margins and paddings in my css but with no luck.
Also for some reason the cover image isn't showing.
Any sugestions?

You can check the prokect here: https://github.com/flukec777/MarsLandpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing body margin in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208335/removing-body-margin-in-css)

Comment: You need to add `body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`

Comment: already have it in * selector at the very start of my css code

Comment: Setting the body's margin and padding to 0 will not work in this case as the problem lies with the css of the div that wraps the nav. The body already has a margin and padding of 0 (AFAIK) and margin and padding are not inherited by default. Also, the universal selector will not work for the margin of the div in this case as the margin setting of the div's class will override the margin setting for the universal selector.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using? The image works on every browser that I have tried.

Comment: I used several: chrome, firefox, vivaldi but they work now. Maybe it was a problem with the file. But yeah thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space is being caused by the `.col` class in Grid.css. The `.col` class contains:

```
.col {
      display: block;
      float:left;
      margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
     }
```

One solution to this problem is to remove or edit the margin property located in the `.col` class. You can do this dynamically through JavaScript, of course.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this was the issue. Totally forgot about those settings in my grid

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `.col` class from `<div class="col span-1-of-2 bg">` on `line 26`.

Editing the `.col` port in css file can have effect in your other tags as well, as you have used that class elsewhere in the document too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind extra space on the top is the div with class .col.span-1-of-2.bg inside header we can remove this space using `margin`.

```
html, body {
    overflow: initial;
}

header .col.span-1-of-2.bg {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```