# Box shadow is stopping before end of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a box shadow on the body and it works perfectly until I add content that makes the page longer than the viewport. The body's background continues however the box shadow stops. Is there a way to make it so the box shadow reaches to the bottom of the page.

CSS:

```
body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

[image]

Full code: https://codepen.io/jsa2025/pen/vYmbzmM

Comment: I just tested your CSS and it seems to be working fine. Can you include your HTML.

Comment: It was flagging it as being too much code. The problem is the overflow doesn't get a shadow

Comment: Does adding a `margin-bottom: 5rem;` style to the `body` get you what you're looking for?

Comment: No, the body continues but the box shadow ends. The picture I added might show what I am referring too.

Comment: @JackAdee I just gave the margin-bottom a try and it is working for me. I will put my codepen for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 490px black;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
  <h1>My Stuff </h1>
</body>
```

Also, take a look at this question regarding the natural Body tag margin. I am it may be what you are looking for:
[Post on natural body tag margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208335/removing-body-margin-in-css)

Comment: i added the codepen to the question so that you could see the full html. It does not appear to be a problem with the margins.

Comment: I guess maybe try including !important to the margin-bottom to force it, it may work. Otherwise, I am out of ideas and hope a CSS wizard comes to help you. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This was an error with the rendering of the preview.

EDIT: The error is still happening

Comment: I see, I am glad you were able to solve it!